# Security concern using AES encryption in golang

Tags: go, cryptography, aes

I want to use the AES implementation in the standard library of crypto in GO.

But as far as I know, I don't have any control where the expanded key is stored and when it is freed, so this can cause a security problem.

I wanted to use memguard (https://github.com/awnumar/memguard) library to secure the key, but I don't have any access to the key after it is expanded.

Any ideas how can I store and manage the key securely?

Comment: Neither the downvotes nor the close votes make sense. This is a very good question and well explained. And now that it's been raised, I have to wonder what on earth the Go standard library is doing to keep key material secure.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Although I did not vote to close the question, there _are_ issues in the question worthy of negative feedback. Notably, there is a mention of an attempt to a solution, but no code to let us understand how that attempt was concretely made. Moreover, the question should not ask for library recommendations.

Comment: @E_net4 Removed part of asking for libraries. I guess explaining how to use memguard to protect the key would expand the question needlessly. Cast the last re-open vote and voted question up as the main question is certainly something that should be answered. Happy to upvote any other answers from Go developers! Off topic: wow, a +4 / -4 ; you don't see that happening all too often!

Answer (score 2):

memguard is the right library for this tool, but it has to be manually dropped into the AES code by replacing the calls to `make([]byte)` with calls to `memguard.New...`

By changing the encryption/decryption expanded key schedules to memguard `LockedBuffer`s, you can control where they live in memory. Further, after the use of the AES block is completed, you can then destroy the underlying `LockedBuffer`s

I was working on the same problem, and I believe I've solved it here: https://github.com/anitgandhi/aesguard

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that it is simply garbage collected and that no attempt is made to destroy the key material otherwise.

The [source](https://golang.org/src/crypto/aes/cipher.go?s=688:736#L44) simply shows that the subkeys are derived and then returned in a pointer to a struct. It doesn't seem that there are any methods defined to destroy the expanded key material.